# In Inbred, what was the problem with where they outsiders were staying?

Tags: plot-explanation, inbred

When they were in the pub they were talking to Jeff, the land lord, when they said where they were staying he dropped a glass and looked shaken.  As he was talking he dropped another one and tried to laugh it off.

What was the issue with where they were staying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of this (which is just an opinion of events) was that it was initially assumed the group were just passing through. However, once it turned out they were staying the barman's attention was piqued. He makes some comment about the near hostel/camping stretch being some 40 miles away. I assumed at this point that if they had been there, they'd have been able to finish their drinks and leave.

However, once its mentioned they are staying locally, at Ravenswood Cottage, I thought it was the sign that the barman now knew they were never going to leave the village and would be killed very soon.

Comment: +1  S you think that the issue was they were staying in the village at all, rather than staying there in particular?

Comment: That's my view, yeah. I've nothing to cite for that, such as director or cast interview. That just seemed the most logical explanation to me.

Comment: It has been a while since I saw the film but this makes sense.